# General offset for all anchors in HTML?

Tags: html, anchor

I have some anchor elements, but they are in absolute position div and the content of the div is so large that it scrolls inside (overflow:auto).

All entries in the div have an anchor on top, but if I go to this anchor I have the element I wanted to directly on top of the side, but I want it in the center. I need something like an offset so I can jump higher than normal.

Comment: Punctuation would really help here...

Comment: hm sry can't explain it better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could always add another div to wrap around it, and then do something like

```
.wrapperdiv{
   position:relative;
   top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: i'm seeking a solution which 
* works for anchors coming in from same page or other page, 
* and which adjusts page-down key-press so that content doesn't get clipped by header, 
* and which allows sib-div footer to scroll up with content-div. Haven't found a solution yet! But i must say, i think the right way would target the whole content div, and not each individual anchor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070758/css-to-make-vertical-scrolling-region-under-fixed-header

Answer (score -1):

You could try a Javascript scroll to correct the position.

Comment: @JeremyStein: Your link is now dead. Here's a link to the internet archive's cached copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20080821211053/http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/12/14/1134573598403.html